# How to match a pandas DataFrame column consisting of a list?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas DataFrame whose column is consisted of a list.

For example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'col1': [['a'], ['b'], ['a'], ['b']]})
df
    col1
0   [a]
1   [b]
2   [a]
3   [b]
```

I want to select those rows that are ['a'], but if I run this code:

```
df['col1'] == ['a']
```

I get an error:

> ValueError: ('Lengths must match to compare', (4,), (1,))

(Same to code `df[df['col1'] == ['a']]`)

What proper code should I use to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
df = df[df['col1'].apply(lambda x: x == ['a'])]
print (df)
  col1
0  [a]
2  [a]
```

Answer (score 1):

Try following

```
df[df['col1'].str[0]=='a']
```

Comment: yop, add to answer where it working

Comment: add if need compare first values of lists use...